# Getting user_id stored using PHP's database session

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, backbone.js, laravel

I am using backbone.js to create a view with a button. When the button is clicked, data containing the logged in user's `user_id` is sent back to the server via AJAX.

**Problem:** I am using a PHP backend (Laravel) which uses database sessions (using a Session class to store the user's `user_id` in the database). How can I retrieve this `user_id` using Javascript/jQuery/backbone.js?

Comment: is the AJAX call to a PHP script? Your user_id should be available as a session variable.

Comment: How should I store this variable so I can access it?

Comment: You may want to use the $_SESSION superglobal.
It's available, after calling 'session_start();' at the beginning of your PHP script.

Comment: If the framework makes it hard to read the session content (*Really?*), the best you can do is consider not using it.

Comment: I have no problem reading the session variable `user_id`, I need a way to pass it to Javascript

Comment: Your question is very vague. You need to show some code, what have you tried? Why do you need the user_id in javascript at all? It should always be available in `$_SESSION` or in whatever session handling mechanism is available in Laravel

Comment: very ture simple store as <span id="usersessionid"><?=$_SESSION['user_id']</span>  and you can grab it using $("usersessionid").html() etc. Not sure that is what you want to achieve

Comment: But in your question you say *data containing the logged in user's user_id is sent back to the server via AJAX*. With your current question, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very ture , store as 
     "span id="usersessionid"" 
and you can grab it using $("usersessionid").html() etc. Not sure that is what you want to achieve.

give span an id=usersessionid and put $_SESSION['user_id'] inside. You can hide that span.

sorry, kind of struggling to get the code displayinghere....